# run java from terminal that depend on external libraries

Tags: java, linux, terminal, lwjgl

I've read around a lot but haven't been able to find a solution yet.

I'm using `lwjgl`, it needs 2 jars and a native library to run: `lwjgl.jar`, `lwjgl_util.jar` and the natives library. I've tried this in every way i could think of, anyway, I'm trying with a command like this at the moment:

```
java - Djava.library.path="libs/natives/" -cp libs/jars/lwjgl.jar:libs/jars/lwjgl_util.jar DisplayTest.class
```

but in every way i try, i get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: DisplayTest/class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DisplayTest.class
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: DisplayTest.class. Program will exit
```

Oh and it might be worth to mention that I'm working on a linux terminal.
Also, i get this to run perfectly fine in eclipse so I can't really understand whats up here.

Comment: is there a blank space right before the `Djava.library.path="libs/natives/"`?? it should be `-Djava.library.path="libs/natives/"`, the construct `-D` is used to define systems properties

Comment: yeah, sorry, it was supposed to be -D, i had some issues when writing the thread :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you just need to pass the class name to java:

```
java -Djava.library.path="libs/natives/" 
     -cp libs/jars/lwjgl.jar:libs/jars/lwjgl_util.jar DisplayTest
```

(linebreaks for readability)

I would try the following:

1) Use the CLASSPATH enviroment variable, as in:

```
  CLASSPATH=.:/path/to/lwjgl/lwjgl.jar:/path/to/lwjgl/lwjgl_util.jar 
  export CLASSPATH
```

Notice the dot (.) at the very beginning of the classpath;

2) Run your java application:

```
  java -Djava.library.path="libs/natives" DisplayTest
```

If this works, add the commands above to a shell script. Good luck!

Comment: I'd like to add that the '/' in "DisplayTest/class" is the clue here. Class names can't have a '/' in them!

Comment: First of all, thanks alot for the reply, however it did work for me. I Still get Could not find the main class: DisplayTest stuff. Even tried to copy your code right off, still didnt work :(

Comment: Sorry, obviously this fixed the error i provided, however the one that appeared after the .class stuff was fixed was so much like it i didnt notice any change for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Try taking off the ".class" e.g.

> java -Djava.library.path="libs/natives/" -cp libs/jars/lwjgl.jar:libs/jars/lwjgl_util.jar DisplayTest.class

Would become:

> java -Djava.library.path="libs/natives/" -cp libs/jars/lwjgl.jar:libs/jars/lwjgl_util.jar DisplayTest

By adding the ".class", you're telling the command that you have a Class called "class" in a directory called "DisplayTest", which is not what you're trying to achieve. This is shown in this line:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: DisplayTest/class
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply! However also, this did not work for me, still get the class not found stuff :(

Comment: @user1295313 That's okay :) What does the output say now?

Comment: @user1295313 Think I may have solved the problem. Try putting ".;" at the start of your classpath e.g. java -Djava.library.path="libs/natives/" -cp .;libs/jars/lwjgl.jar:libs/jars/lwjgl_util.jar DisplayTest

Comment: @user1295313 Also, you have used ":" instead of ";" between your jar files, only just noticed.

Answer (score 0):

when triggering java command use -cp or -classpath. Enter just `java` command to see the usage

Answer (score 0):

I also got a similar error.

Just include your working directory , (where you have your own class), along with the libraries that you need in your classpath  at runtime.

`NoCLassDefFoundError` occurs when the machine is unable to find your `.class` files during runtime (even though they have been compiled ,i.e it won't give an error while compiling but only during runtime)

STEP 1: to compile
  javac -classpath "path/to/lib1:path/to/lib2" yourfile.java
STEP 2: to run
 java - classpath "path/to/lib1:path/to/lib2:path/to/your/currentdirectory/wherethedotclass/filearecreated/" yourfile